# Beef-xss Webhooks & Port Forwarding / NAT

Tags: port-forwarding, beef

The scenario is:

- I am running a test webpage with apache2 with the beef hook embedded on a kali box (VM)
- My router has a port forward set to the IP address of the VM and forwarding to the port on which apache is hosting the page.

The router does have a static IP address, but for some reason, the beef-xss hook does not seem to "activate" when the webpage is opened from an external network endpoint.

Am I correct in assuming another port forward is required for the webhook to communicate back to the vm on beef-xss' port?

[image]

Comment: We need a couple more troubleshooting details: 1. the external client reaches the Apache page successfully? 2. The web-hook is a client-side javascript script that is meant to point back to another VM? 3. There is no routing between the external client and the VM to which the javascript points? 4. why is beef running on another VM and not the web server?

Comment: So both the Apache web server and Beef installation is running on the Kali VM.
The client can reach the webpage but beef fails to hook the client browser.
The port forward on the router uses the VM IP address and apache's web port (80).
The webhook auto-generated by Beef attempts to connect back on port 3000 and has been added to the webpage running on apache.
Hook: <script src="http://IP:3000/hook.js"></script>

Comment: And have you provided a port forward for port 3000?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Found solution: Another port forward is required for the webhook's port.

Comment: As expected, this is more of a networking config issue (port forwarding) than a security issue.